# Explaining result report at XMR-STAK

Tags: mining-theory, xmr-stak-amd

Here is the example of result report by XMR-STAK:

```
RESULT REPORT
Difficulty       : 13214
Good results     : 6330 / 6331 (100.0 %)
Avg result time  : 10.0 sec
Pool-side hashes : 83681055

Top 10 best results found:
|  0 |         73934015 |  1 |         70496651 |
|  2 |         42197234 |  3 |         37331106 |
|  4 |         25657807 |  5 |         23286815 |
|  6 |         15785406 |  7 |         14788188 |
|  8 |         13255493 |  9 |          7888863 |
```

Would be nice to know what exactly these lines mean:

1. Avg result time
2. Pool-side hashes
3. Top 10 best results found

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting from the hip, but

Average time: time between good results

Pool side hashes: all the hashes you sent (Depends on your diff and H/s)

Top 10: results with the highest difficulty

(could be, and probably, off base)